Creating "horseshoe" polylines from lines in QGIS
I need to generate “horseshoe”/U lines that can be imported into another program for hydrological adjustments.
I have the correct centerlines, but I can’t quite figure out how to generate these lines around, as shown in the example.

This must be done for many places, so it must be automated. I think there is no built-in tool for this, isn't it?
Is this possible to execute in QGIS?

I am deleting the python tag because no code was provided. Can you also explain how these “horseshoe”/U lines could be generated? So other users can answer your question codelessly.

You can use "Geometry by Expression" to buffer each line, envelope it to create a rectangle and create a line between the rectangle vertices 2-3, 3-4, 4-5 and union the three lines.
Change the distance 20 to the width/separation you want.
collect_geometries(
        with_variable(
            name:='box',
            value:=oriented_bbox(buffer(geometry:=$geometry, distance:=20)),
            expression:=array_foreach(
                            array(2,3,4),
                            expression:=
                            collect_geometries(
                                make_line(
                                    point_n(geometry:=@box, index:=@element),
                                    point_n(geometry:=oriented_bbox(buffer($geometry,20)), index:=@element+1)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
            )
    )



I figured it out with a Python script, that uses the attribute toplength as the perpendicular length. Added it here if anyone needs it.
# Get the active layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()  # Ensure a layer is selected
if not layer:
    print("No active layer found. Please select a layer.")
    raise Exception("Active layer is required")

toplength_field = "toplength"  # Replace with your field name

# Create a new memory layer to store results
output_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"LineString?crs={layer.crs().authid()}", "U_Shapes", "memory")
output_provider = output_layer.dataProvider()

# Copy fields (attributes) from the original layer
output_provider.addAttributes(layer.fields())
output_layer.updateFields()

# Iterate over features in the layer
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    geometry = feature.geometry()
    
    # Check if geometry is a MultiLineString or LineString
    if geometry.type() != QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:
        continue  # Skip non-line geometries
    
    # Handle MultiLineString geometries
    if geometry.isMultipart():
        lines = geometry.asMultiPolyline()
    else:
        lines = [geometry.asPolyline()]
    
    # Process each line in the MultiLineString
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) < 2:
            continue  # Skip invalid geometries
        
        start, end = line[0], line[-1]
        toplength = feature[toplength_field]
        
        dx, dy = end.x() - start.x(), end.y() - start.y()
        length = (dx**2 + dy**2)**0.5  # Calculate line length
        
        # Normalize vector for direction
        nx, ny = -dy / length, dx / length  # Perpendicular unit vector
        
        # Calculate perpendicular offsets
        corner1 = QgsPoint(start.x() + nx * toplength, start.y() + ny * toplength)
        corner2 = QgsPoint(start.x() - nx * toplength, start.y() - ny * toplength)
        top_point = QgsPoint(corner1.x() + dx, corner1.y() + dy)
        bottom_point = QgsPoint(corner2.x() + dx, corner2.y() + dy)
        
        # Create U-shaped geometry
        u_shape = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([corner1, top_point, bottom_point, corner2])
        
        # Create a new feature
        new_feature = QgsFeature(output_layer.fields())  # Initialize with the output layer's schema
        new_feature.setGeometry(u_shape)
        new_feature.setAttributes(feature.attributes())  # Copy attributes from the original feature
        
        # Add the new feature to the output layer
        output_provider.addFeature(new_feature)

# Add the output layer to the QGIS project
output_layer.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(output_layer)
print("U-shaped geometries with attributes created and added to the map.")

